# How do I solve this conditional probabilities problem with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian

If **P( c<sub>j</sub> | x<sub>i</sub> )** are already known, where **i=1,2,...n; j=1,2,...k;**

How do I calculate/estimate:
**P( c<sub>j</sub> | x<sub>l</sub> , x<sub>m</sub> , x<sub>n</sub> )**, where **j=1,2,...k; l,m,n [belongs to http://latex.mathoverflow.net/jsMath/fonts/cmsy10/alpha/120/char32.png](http://latex.mathoverflow.net/jsMath/fonts/cmsy10/alpha/120/char32.png) {1,2,...n}** ?

Comment: probably better on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: I don't think so,they only accept questions of mathematician level and this question is more about implementation.

Comment: Don't you mean "*probability* problem"?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT2** (following the OP's comment)

From [bayes rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) we know that `P(C|x1,x2,x3) ~  P(C)*P(x1,x2,x3|C)` and therefore for classification, you compute that expression for all `C=j` and predict the most likely class ([MAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori)).

Now to compute `P(x1,x2,x3|C)`, for [i.i.d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically-distributed_random_variables) observations, this can be written as: `P(x1,x2,x3|C) = P(x1|C)*P(x2|C)*P(x3|C)`, which given a parametric model each could be computed easily.

Comment: No,seems this is not what I'm doing.`C_i` denotes Categories,while `X_i` denotes samples.So my question is how to classify different samples.

Comment: given what little details you're sharing, no wonder both @aduric and I misunderstood the question!

Comment: Sorry man,now that you understand what I mean,do you have a solution ?Can I just use **P( c_j | x_l ) * P( c_j | x_m ) * P( c_j | x_n )** to approximate **P( c_j | x_l , x_m , x_n )**

Comment: Seems BNT can also be used to do this job by setting `sizeNodes` to `[2 2 2 2]`?

Comment: It seems to me `independent is` enough,why do you require it to be `identically distributed` too?

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the question. He didn't ask about Bayes Nets, nor do I think he needs them.

Comment: there was some confusion at first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [site](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs470ta/goodrich/fall2005/MATLAB/BayesEstimator.html) can help? I'm assuming your trying to implement the Bayes rule in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible without further information or simplifying assumptions.

The conditional probability P(A|B,C) is not (completely/at all :) determined by P(A|B) and P(A|C).